# Problem with installing extension via composer

Tags: magento2, composer

I want to install the extension via the composer. But when I try to type the password I get this problem:

```
Warning from repo.magento.com: You haven't provided your Magento authentication keys. For instructions, visit https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html
Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
  Username: 6df1d39ccaf9e6bc5a59e7b0e2f63be6
  Password:
```

I can't type or paste the password. 
What is the problem?

Comment: whatever type in password it's invisible so you just type password or paste password and click enter button

Comment: You can paste or type. if you paste and you can not show that. then it does not make sense not paste. just paste it and press enter. so maybe some message comes there. and on that message, you can go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a security reason, Command line will not showing you a password while you are typing so don't worry just type correct pwd, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can paste or type. if you paste and you can not show that. then it does not make sense not paste. just paste it and press enter. so maybe some message comes there. and on that message, you can go ahead.
```